# Angular 2 with spring mvc 4.2.6 and spring security 4.0.1 with CORS filter

Tags: spring-mvc, angular, spring-security

We have Angular 2 app with Spring Security and Spring MVC for REST API. Before we implemented authentication both on frontend and backed, it was working fine. Since we added simple basic authentication, we are having problem about sending custom auth token to backend. I have two filters setup, one we CORSFilter setup in `web.xml` and has code like this

```java
if (request.getHeader("Access-Control-Request-Method") != null && "OPTIONS".equals(request.getMethod())) {
    // CORS "pre-flight" request
    response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE");
    response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-AUTH-TOKEN");
    response.addHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "60000");
}
```

All API requests are being intercepted by this filter and as you see it is allowing our custom auth token.

Now we enter the Spring Security filter chain where we have custom filter to validate that token, which tries to get the `X-AUTH-TOKEN` from request header and it always retuns `null`.

Can anyone tell me what might be setting this value to `null`? I did check that my frontend is sending `X-AUTH-TOKEN` with correct value based on Firefox debugger tool and if I take that token and use postman client to make that REST API call then also it is working fine. Only problem happens when I test the frontend with Chrome or Firefox.

Note: Frontend is served on port 4200 and backend is served on port 8080.

Answer (score 0):

ok, after some clues from above replies, I realized that in my custom spring security filter, i was trying to access "x-auth-token" on every request for api. But in case of CORS, browser make OPTIONS pre flight request before it make actual request.

After adding check to ignore OPTIONS method, things worked fine. So now my custom JWT Auth filter only check for presence of token in GET,POST,PUT and DELETE request.

Also as per suggestion from "dur", I have also removed CORSFilter i developed since spring mvc 4.1.x provides inbuild CORS support and you can customize it as if it is your own custom filter. Thank you "dur" for your link.

Answer (score -1):

You might want to add OPTIONS to allowed methods.

Comment: So after adding "OPTIONS" method in CORS filter, i do see that response for OPTIONS request which was made by Chrome is getting same header back. And then i also check actual get request is sending that request header to server, and still in custom JWT filter, it is returning null.